# Ajax jquery to stop running when windows is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

All, 
I am new to MVC. I have built an application where a button click performs

- get market data (lengthy operation).
- data message and upload to database.

This is what the JavaScript function looks like:

```
function OnClick(s, e) {
        if (true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("DataFileUpload", "ImportData")",
                data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
                dataType: "text",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function () { lpImport.Show(); },
                success: function (msg) {
                    ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                    ImportSuccessMessage.SetVisible(true);
                    ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
                    lpImport.Hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr)
                    ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

What is happening right now is - When users close the browser in the middle of the run, controller action is still running. I can see that in my log. 
How do I make browser close to stop running my controller action DataFileUpload ?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the abort function from the XMLHttpRequest that $.ajax() returns.
[abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort). If the request has been sent already, this method will abort the request.

Something like:

```
var xhr;
function OnClick(s, e) {
        if (true) {
            xhr = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("DataFileUpload", "ImportData")",
                data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
                dataType: "text",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function () { lpImport.Show(); },
                success: function (msg) {
                    ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                    ImportSuccessMessage.SetVisible(true);
                    ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
                    lpImport.Hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr)
                    ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                }
            });
        }
    }

function closeBrowser() {
  xhr.abort();
}
```

but this will only cancel the event on the client. You should also cancel the request on the serverside.

Comment: Great. Thanks I will try.

Comment: abort works for me . on the server side I used cancellation token and checked for IsCancellationRequested and then aborted.